# Boost.Test alternative test module initialization function cannot convert parameter to 'boost::unit_test::init_unit_test_func'

Tags: c++, boost, boost-test

I started working with Boost.Test and trying some examples, and things were going so-far-so-good. But I'm having trouble with http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/test-organization/manual-nullary-test-case.html, example 9. I literally copy-paste the code from example 9, then the *only* change I make is to replace BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK with BOOST_TEST_NO_MAIN (I'm linking statically), but I get the error:

```
error C2664: 'boost::unit_test::unit_test_main' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'bool (__cdecl *)(void)' to 'boost::unit_test::init_unit_test_func'
          This conversion requires a reinterpret_cast, a C-style cast or function-style cast
```

Any thoughts on why and what I can do to fix it? Thanks.